# How to call token functions without source code

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

I created a basic `MintableToken` with OpenZeppelin framework but I have lost my source code. I want to mint more of my tokens and I am trying to do so through web3.py

Here is my current code

```
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/MYAPI"))

web3.eth.defaultAccount = 'MYACC_ADDR'
abi = [
    {
        "constant": False,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "_to",
                "type": "address"
            },
             {
                "name": "_amount",
                "type": "uint256"
            }
        ],
        "name": "mint",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "bool"
            }
        ],
        "payable": False,
        "stateMutability": "pure",
        "type": "function"
    }
]

address = web3.toChecksumAddress('CONTRACT_ADDR') # FILL IN YOUR ACTUAL ADDRESS
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=address, abi=abi)

print(contract.functions.mint('MYACC_ADDR', 200).call())
```

Running this code via `python3 mint.py` prints `True` , but the contract isn't actually called. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"stateMutability": "pure"
```

That's wrong and means that by default `web3.py` will make a local call to a node instead of sending an actual transaction.

I believe it should be this instead:

```
"stateMutability": "nonpayable"
```

Of course, after that change note that you'll need to provide `web3.py` with a `from` address and a private key to sign the transaction with.